# Не могу загрузить репозиторий

Tags: git, github

```
error: Trace: 7c57dfa08af01c8035d347b05d683502d31ce6007ca400e86dfa52210a54c093
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File Library/PlayerDataCache/Win/Data/sharedassets1.assets.resS is 155.54 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File Library/Artifacts/28/2812017d2734b826d2bb83643edc359e is 128.08 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
```

Из а этой ошибки я не могу загрузить репозиторий. Я в первые загружаю репозиторий так что не удивляйтесь моей тупости.

Comment: ну у вас в ошибке все написано, гитхаб не позволяет загружать файлы больше 100 мб, а у вас в репозитории есть файлы, превышающие этот объем. Если эти файлы не являются необходимыми в репозитории - добавьте их в gitignore.

Comment: если эти файлы необходимы, посмотрите в сторону git LFS:  https://git-lfs.github.com он позволяет не хранить в git большие файлы, а только ссылке, а сами файлы идут на ваш FS, например S3

Answer (score 1):

я не очень разбираюсь но может поможет)

по ошибке кажется что вы загружаете что-то очень большое, хотелось бы узнать что это

> удаленный: ошибка: File Library / PlayerDataCache / Win / Data / sharedassets1.assets.resS составляет 155,54 МБ; это превышает ограничение на размер файла GitHub в 100,00 МБ

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: Я загружаю Unity проект. Файлы .gitattributes и .gitignore есть.

Comment: @стасПетрушков так а что это за большие файлы? Они там точно нужны?

Comment: Я не знаю. А удалять его мне страшно.